# Correspondence between defined api resources and apis that we develop in a resource server

Tags: identityserver4

What is the correspondence between a defined API resource and the API's that we develop in our resource server?
I have some API's in my resource server app. These API's are defined in IdentityServer4 if I understand it correctly.

Setup a client app to use the apis securely with following code using `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation`:

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
  Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
  RequireHttpsMetadata = false,                
  ApiName = "api1"
});
```

The question is which of the API's I must provide for   `ApiName = "api1"` in the above MW? Any client app can use only one api?

Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use the `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` in an API that is protected by the Identityserver4. The ApiName should be the name of a defined `ApiResource` in the IdentityServer. A client can have access to multiple Api's just by letting the client request more Scopes from the IdentityServer.

You would add the ApiResource in your startup something like:
`services.AddIdentityServer().AddInMemoryApiResources(new[] { new ApiResource("Api1", "Api1") });`